# CSS: set fallback background-image without image()

Tags: css

The goal is is to set a fallback image in pure CSS, without using the [image() notation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#image-notation). Otherwise, the goal would be this code:

```css
#some-id{
      background-image: image('default-image.png', 'fallback-image.png');
}
```

Indeed, in the context rising this question, the written CSS is processed and the  follwing code :

```css
#some-id{
      background-image: /*@var default-image */;
}
```

will return:

```css
#some-id{
      background-image: url('/URL/TO/default-image.png');
}
```

As it is, there is no way to pass more than one parameter to this preprocessor.

One already explored idea would be to set immediately after the same id which have a background-image set to none. Indeed, the preprocessor do return `none` when there is no matching picture. So, in code:

```css
#some-id{
      background-image: /*@var default-image */;
}

#some-id[background-image=none]{
      background-image: /*@var fallback-image */;
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
background-image: url("image.png"), url("fallback-image.png");
```

It will superimpose pictures and so you can play with the images transparency or no to get the expected result.

Answer (score -1):

```
#some-id {
      background-image: url('fallback-image.png');
      background-image: image('default-image.png');
}
```